# Git Pull Without Overwriting Committed Files

Tags: git

I have made changes to some files and have pushed the changes to the remote repository.  Another person pulls from the repo and decides to delete / modify some of the files that I had just pushed, and then he pushes.

This remote repository has security set so that you may only pull (or push to it with a special command).  I need to pull to get someone else's changes but don't want his to overwrite my own (which are already committed).  As I said, I can not do a revert, I can only pull.

I need a way so that I can pull (which will overwrite some changes but apply other critical updates) then undo only the changes that last pull did to the files I had pushed originally.  Ideally, by "undoing" the changes, the files that I had originally committed were now uncommitted; i.e.  if I typed "git status", I would see the same list as I did right before I committed and pushed originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. checkout your commit with the files you originally added
2. Git reset HEAD~1 #this will move the files from your commit to staging
3. git stash # this will store your current not committed changes.
4. git pull --rebase
5. git stash pop #restore the stored changes from your original commit on top of pulled changes

There might be conflicts after this which you will have to resolve. You can also checkout unneded files after step 2 and before step 3 to not save them.
See [git stash man](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. But in any case, you could simply make a branch for your version like so:

`git checkout -b mywork master`

It will default to using the master branch, so you can omit the master part. But if you are working on a different branch, replace master with whatever branch you want to base you new branch on.

Changes not committed will also be present.

Then pull in his changes. And do whatever merging needs done to master if necessary.

Comment: That command makes a new branch with the changes of the original branch (the one I pushed from).  If I pull to this one, I have the same issue that my code is still deleted / modified (I tried it).

Comment: `git checkout master` and use that for the merged version. If you don't want your code in master either commit it to your new branch or do `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`